# How to pass arguments to nodejs modules

Tags: node.js

I am using nodeJS, and I want to pass argument to the module like this

```
function (req, res, next) {
   var test = require('test')({key: 'abc'});
}
```

and when I write my module like this, I am able to get the value of key inside module

```
module.exports= function(key) {
   console.log(key);
}
```

But If I write my module like this:

```
exports.fun1 = function(req, res, next) {
    //something here
}

exports.fun2 = function(req, res, next) {
    //something here
}
```

then how can I get the value of my argument ?

Comment: What argument, what value, where?

Answer (score 3):

you can save it in a local var or make a constructor like function in your module

something like this

```
var _arg1, _arg2;
module.exports = {

    ctor: function(arg1, arg2, etc) {
        _arg1=arg1;
        _arg2=arg2
    },



    moreFunction: function() {
        //use _arg1 etc
    }

}
```

and then usage will be:

```
var myModule = require('myModule');
myModule.ctor("bla", 2, null);
myModule.moreFunction();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work if the `ctor` was called multiple times with different arguments.

Comment: Its not intended to work class-like way. Can easily change it so

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it.  You make your exports be a single function that accepts your arguments and then you `return` from that function the module contents like this:

Usage:

```
var test = require('test')({key: 'abc'});

function (req, res, next) {
   test.fun1(yourArgsHere);
}
```

In your module:

```
// module constructor function
module.exports = function(options) {
   console.log(options);
   return {
       fun1: function(req, res, next) {
           // can access options.key here
           // something here
       },
       fun2: function(req, res, next) {
           // can access options.key here
           // something here
       }
   };
}
```